# How to detect Creative Sound blaster Audigy 2?

Tags: 10.10, sound, 64-bit, sound-blaster

I have installed a pci 7.1 sound card Creative Sound Blaster Audigy 2, on my 10.10 Ubuntu 64 bit installation. I have disabled the on board sound card from bios. I boot and the system cannot recognize my "new" sound card.

When I execute

```
aplay -l
```

I get this responce:

```
aplay: device_list:235: no soundcards found...
```

I take a guess and I think it is probably something wrong with my sound modules.

Comment: Just as a heads up, this used to work. But now appears it's broken. Additionally lspci doesn't report it correctly, and shows it as a firewire device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems for the troubleshooting steps. These steps include actions to retrieve information that describe your sound hardware in detail.